# nhibernate filter not working (unknown filter parameter)?

Tags: nhibernate

I have a filter like this:

```
<filter name="partnerIdFilter" condition="partner_id IN (:partnerId)"/>
```

and the `partnerId` parameter is defined like this:

```
<filter-def name="partnerIdFilter">    
    <filter-param name="partnerId" type="int[]"/>
</filter-def>
```

and the filter is enabled like this:

```
currentSession.EnableFilter("partnerIdFilter").SetParameterList("partnerId", specification.GetFilterValues());
```

But I get an NHibernate exception `Undefined filter parameter [partnerId]`

How can I fix this? Another filter in the same mapping file is working without any problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it's an old question, but I just learned the answer to this myself. The type has to be either a basic type or inherit from IType, ICompositeUserType, IUserType, ILIfecycle, an Enum or has to be Serializable. If it's none of those, then you get this rather cryptic error.

Comment: For those of you who still have doubts on how to fix the example above you just have to go from this:  
    `<filter-param name="partnerId" type="int[]"/>`  
to this:  
    `<filter-param name="partnerId" type="int"/>`